# How is the definition of a regular curve related to the definition of a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

The definition of a regular curve is usually given by the non-vanishing of the tangent vector to every parametrization of curve at every point on the interval. On the other hand, the definition of a regular surface is given by saying that it is a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ with all the standard properties. While solving some exercises, I came across a puzzling question which relates both interpretations.

[image]

I can prove that the inverse image of a regular value of a differential function $f:U\subseteq \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ is a regular surface. However, I could not prove the above statement. Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> The key tool is the implicit function theorem. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I got the point and I did use implicit function theorem to prove that the inverse image of a regular value of a differentiable function from R^3 to R is a regular surface. But, I am confused how to derive that tangent vector does not vanish for the inverse image of a regular value of a differentiable function from R^2 to R.

Comment: The implicit function theorem can be applied directly to a function of two variables, with the desired conclusion. (Please feel free to type up your own answer! <> If this doesn't help, maybe edit the question to give the precise statement of the implicit function theorem you have?)